# Quickbooks Monetary Calculation Logic

Tags: quickbooks

I am working on rewriting some MiddleWare that several of my company's applications employ to communicate with Quickbooks.  In the process, I am trying so solve a problem that we frequently encounter.  In short, the transaction amount that we calculate in our POS and other modules is often a few pennies different that the transaction amount that is calculated by Quickbooks.  This is especially a problem in the POS because our system does not send the sales receipts to Quickbooks until the shift is reconciled at the register (i.e. end of batch).  During the batch, our system stores transactions in a SQL Server database and then sends those transactions to Quickbooks when the clerk closes their batch.  If the amount of the transaction is our system is off by a few pennies due to precision/rounding differences then one of two things happen depending on the SDK version.

1) Quickbooks rejects transaction because the Payment Item on the sales receipt in Quickbooks does not equal the amount of the sales receipt.
2) The transaction is posted to Quickbooks with a different amount than the transaction in our system. (In this case we are not putting a payment item on the sales receipt because it is not supported in older SDKs.  This causes many bookeepers to get upset).

Does anyone familiar with this interface know where I can find some documentation on the logic Intuit uses to perform monetary calculations so that I can fix this issue?  Again, the reason that this is happening is that we are calculating the transaction amount in our POS (i.e. items, discounts, taxes, etc...) and when the sales receipt is sent to QB the amount is occasionally off by a few pennies.  If I had documentation on the precision and math logic used by Intuit I could fix this issue.  Thanks in advance.

I have searched everywhere for this documentation and even posted an unanswered message on the Intuit Developer Network so I'm not sure if such documentation even exists.

Comment: This sounds like something you should be discussing with QB support.  And without some sort of concrete example, it would be really difficult to even hazard a guess about what is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I will get a sample of a transaction to post here.  It generally happens when there are one or more discounts and one or more taxes associated with the transaction so I think that it has to do with the way that we are calculating those in our logic.  Unfortunately, I work for a small company that is too cheap to pay for Intuit support.  In the past, they have just blamed Intuit for these issues which I do not agree with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After joining Intuit Developer Network, I finally acquired the information I needed.  For specific Intuit questions such as these, I highly recommend joining their network.  The solution may not be instantaneous but, I highly recommend involving the Intuit developers.